How to write a formula to an Excel spreadsheet that uses table column name in Python using openpyxl?
I've got a spreadsheet with some formulas in a table that would be clearer if I could use the Column Header name instead of the column letter. Can't figure out how.
Using the Implicit Intersection Operator (@), I can manually insert the formula in the spreadsheet like (assuming headers are Donuts, Dollars, Total):
A2 = 5
B2 = 20
C2 = [@[Donuts]] * [@[Dollars]]

I get 100 in Total column
But if I do something like (assuming my headers are Donuts, Dollars, Total):
sheet['A2'] = 5
sheet['B2'] = 20
sheet['C2'] = '=[@[Donuts]] * [@[Dollars]]'

I get a formula error when I try to open the spreadsheet and Excel removes the formula.
But I can do:
sheet['C2'] = '= A2 * B2'

and I get 100 in C2 (Total)

sheet['C2'] = '=Table1[[#This Row],[A]]*Table1[[#This Row],[B]]'

Does the trick
